# mod-write dynamic links with htaccess doesn't work

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want that when I enter to

```
http://localhost/web/post/136
```

It will go to

```
http://localhost/web/file/home/page.php?post=136
```

This is what I did:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/post/([0-9]+)$ file/home/page.php?post=$1 [last]
```

What I need to change?

Comment: The leading slash will never match in per-directory rules.

Comment: That rewrite rule doesn't match *anything* in what you want. Did you just blindly copy that from somewhere else?

Comment: yeah sorry, fixed the url. But its still doesn't work

Comment: `RewriteRule ^post/([0-9]+)/?$ file/home/page.php?post=$1 [L,QSA,NC]`

Comment: @anubhava great it work, but its look diffrently. The images doesn't anymore, and the design look diffrently. Any idea what might do it?

Comment: You just need base tag in your HTML

Answer (score 0):

As per your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35782381/mod-write-dynamic-links-with-htaccess-doesnt-work#comment59242255_35782381) , To fix the js ,css and other relative links on rewritten urls ,you can add the following base tag to the head of your document :

```
<base href="/">
```